# Define custom LSTM Cell in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I use Keras with TensorFlow as back-end. If I want to make a modification to an LSTM cell, such as "removing" the output gate, how can I do it? It is a multiplicative gate, so somehow I will have to set it to fixed values so that whatever multiplies it, has no effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you should define your [own custom layer](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/). If you need some intuition how to implement your own cell see [LSTMCell](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1765) in Keras repository. E.g. your custom cell will be:

```
class MinimalRNNCell(keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        self.units = units
        self.state_size = units
        super(MinimalRNNCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      name='kernel')
        self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units, self.units),
            initializer='uniform',
            name='recurrent_kernel')
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs, states):
        prev_output = states[0]
        h = K.dot(inputs, self.kernel)
        output = h + K.dot(prev_output, self.recurrent_kernel)
        return output, [output]
```

Then, use [`tf.keras.layers.RNN`](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) to use your cell:

```
cell = MinimalRNNCell(32)
x = keras.Input((None, 5))
layer = RNN(cell)
y = layer(x)

# Here's how to use the cell to build a stacked RNN:

cells = [MinimalRNNCell(32), MinimalRNNCell(64)]
x = keras.Input((None, 5))
layer = RNN(cells)
y = layer(x)
```

Comment: Thank you. And how does this manual approach differ from managing LSTM state with the 'stateful' and other parameters?

Comment: It would be good to show at least the method arguments: build(self, batch_input_shape) and call(self, inputs, states), plus optionally `training` and `mask`, and what's returned by these methods: nothing for the build() method, and inputs and states for the call() method.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to replicate the code for multiple inputs. So I changed y=layer([input_1,input_2]) and also change the shape of input_shape but its throwing errors as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58408106/define-custom-lstm-with-multiple-inputs. How to overcome the error ... any idea?