# how to use a tensor instead of variable for the weights and biases in LSTM cells

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to create LSTM cells, but instead of creating new variables for the weights and biases in the network, the weights and biases in LSTM cells are coming from the output of another network, i.e., I need to be able to pass a tensor (instead of variable for example using reuse) to LSTM cells to be used for weights and biases. Is there anyway to do it in Tensorflow? Note that my goal is not to define LSTM, but to know whether there is any way to pass tensors in the current implementation.

Comment: A poor workaround is to pass `trainable=False` and then assign the output values of the first networks to the weights, although that is far from a convenient solution. Or rewire the graph after creating it with [Graph Editor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.graph_editor), also quite complicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define custom LSTM Cell in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54231440/define-custom-lstm-cell-in-keras)

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py), there really does not seem to be much of a way around it. [`tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/rnn_cell/LSTMCell) creates the weights and implements the LSTM state calculation, so looks like you cannot have without the other.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a duplicate of the other question, because you really just want a regular LSTM but with different weights (also this one is not Keras in principle), but possibly the only "good" way of doing this is by implementing your own subclass of [`tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/rnn_cell/RNNCell), very similar to [`tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/rnn_cell/LSTMCell) (in fact you might consider subclassing that instead) but without the variable creation.

Comment: (fwiw I think this is a mistake in the API... the LSTM mathematical definition and its use as a trainable layer should be separated, in the same way there is [`tf.nn.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) and [`tf.layers.Conv2D`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/Conv2D))

Comment: @Amir I don't think this is the same question. The aim is just to pass tensors to LSTM not to define custom LSTM.

Comment: @jdehesa thanks for the comments. Perhaps the easiest way is to inherit a class from LSTM.

Answer (score 0):

## Keras + TensorFlow

Keras runs on top of TensorFlow by default now and has [an LSTM layer](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm) that can be called in your model. This will automatically pass weights as tensor between layers.

```
>>>IN>>>
nb_words  = min(MAX_NB_WORDS, len(word_index))
lstm_out = MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(nb_words,EMBEDDING_DIM,input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH))
model.add(LSTM(50))
#model.add(Attention(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH))
model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

>>>OUT>>>
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 100, 160)          480000    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 50)                42200     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 153       
=================================================================
Total params: 522,353
Trainable params: 522,353
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

[Here is a notebook where you can see it used.](https://github.com/BrittonWinterrose/Drug_Review_NLP/blob/master/03_Drug_LSTM_w_Custom_Stopwords.ipynb)

Comment: I don't think this solves the issue unfortunately. As you can see `lstm_1` in your model has 42,200 parameters. The goal of the question is to not have any trainable parameters in the LSTM layer, but instead use the output of another network in place of the parameters.