# Tensorflow: Low level LSTM implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am looking for a low-level implementation of a RNN with LSTM cells in Tensorflow. I already implemented several feedforward networks where I used low-level APIs. This helped me a lot to understand the inner workings of ANNs. Can I do the same for a RNN or is it recommended to use the Tensorflow implementation of a LSTM cell (`tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell`)? I didn't find any low-level implementation of a RNN in Tensorflow. Where could I find such a low-level implementation? Is Tensorflow designed for this at all? Where could I start?
I hope that a few of my questions can be answered here

Answer (score 2):

#### 1) Using tf.scan

The low-level implementation of RNN can be achieved with [tf.scan](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scan) function. For example, for SimpleRNN, the implementation will be similar to:

```
# our RNN variables
Wx = tf.get_variable(name='Wx', shape=[embedding_size, rnn_size])
Wh = tf.get_variable(name='Wh', shape=[rnn_size, rnn_size])
bias_rnn = tf.get_variable(name='brnn', initializer=tf.zeros([rnn_size]))


# single step in RNN
# simpleRNN formula is `tanh(WX+WH)`
def rnn_step(prev_hidden_state, x):
    return tf.tanh(tf.matmul(x, Wx) + tf.matmul(prev_hidden_state, Wh) + bias_rnn)

# our unroll function
# notice that our inputs should be transpose
hidden_states = tf.scan(fn=rnn_step,
                        elems=tf.transpose(embed, perm=[1, 0, 2]),
                        initializer=tf.zeros([batch_size, rnn_size]))

# covert to previous shape
outputs = tf.transpose(hidden_states, perm=[1, 0, 2])

# extract last hidden
last_rnn_output = outputs[:, -1, :]
```

See complete example [here](https://gist.github.com/hadifar/3154270878b82ec99e059384d1cd5849).

#### 2) Using AutoGraph

`tf.scan` is a for-loop that you can implement it [Auto-graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autograph) API as well:

```
from tensorflow.python import autograph as ag

@ag.convert()
def f(x):
# ...
for ch in chars:
      cell_output, (state, output) = cell.call(ch, (state, output))
      hidden_outputs.append(cell_output)
hidden_outputs = autograph.stack(hidden_outputs)
# ...
```

See complete example with autograph API [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/autograph/examples/notebooks/rnn_keras_estimator.ipynb#scrollTo=9v8AJouiC44V).

#### 3) Implement in Numpy

If you still need to go deeper inside to implement RNN see [this](http://blog.varunajayasiri.com/numpy_lstm.html) tutorial that implements RNN with numpy.

#### 4) Custom RNN cell in Keras

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54231866/1462770).